# Why do we get "messages endpoint is deprecated" when writing messages to facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, api, graph, message, messenger

We are using the graph api to manage company pages for our customers. We (our customers) have upgraded with the pages_messaging permission (instead of read_page_mailboxes) and we can read private messages (messenger) as before.

But since the fb upgrade yesterday (30 june) we cannot write replies to private messages (messenger) via the graph api using: POST {conversation-id}/messages.
We get error (#12) : “messages endpoint is deprecated”

The documentation says this should not be deprecated until v6.0 is ended.
We are using default version of the graph api (currently v3.0).

So why can't we use graph api to write replies to messenger chat conversation on company pages now?

Answer (score 0):

It's an ongoing issue by the looks of it.
We use Zendesk for replying to customers and they are also having issues posting to the messages endpoint as confirmed by their support.

This happened a couple of months ago and was resolved.

I have reported this issue to facebook.